# How can I access pre-existing UV maps in an fbx?

Tags: texturing, materials, uv, outliner

I am trying to clean up some mistakes in an fbx model that I have and it would help tremendously if I could access the pre-existing UV maps in the model.

My outliner shows one mesh with multiple materials that have multiple textures underneath it.

[image: Outliner image]

I want to access the UV map for one of these textures.

Unfortunately, the UV/Image Editor shows one ridiculously complicated UV map that combines the UV maps of all the textures.

[image]

How can I select just the one UV map that comes with only one of the textures?

Comment: What is meant by "pre-existing UV maps"? If you have 2 versions of the same mesh, one with new UV map and one with old UV map corresponding to the UV layout used when textures were made then you can bake textures from the mesh with older UV maps to the mesh with newer ones. If all you have is mesh with new UV maps then no way to get old UV map back.

Comment: I might just be making a wrong assumption then. Would you expect EnvSamplerTex.006 and 007 in the image to contain the original UV map?

Comment: Hi  bds. There is nothing 'pre' about the existance of UV maps the way I see it. Also when you import anything to Blender it stops being in a format such as FBX and becomes data in a blend file so you are actually **using existing UV Maps in Blender** and not at all 'accessing pre-existing UV Maps in an FBX file'.

Answer (score 1):

All existing UV maps can be accessed by simply selecting them in the Properties Editor, Data tab in the UV map list. They will be previewed in the viewport when selected, and you need to select the active one for rendering by clicking the camera icon:

[image]

When you need to use a few UV maps in a shader, you can specify the vector input for any texture to be the correct UV map with the node not so surprisingly called 'UV Map':

[image]

Answer (score -1):

So all I had to do was to open the properties's panel material pane where all the materials are listed. Then selecting them and clicking on deselect allowed me to isolate the one I needed.

[image: Solution]

Hope this helps someone. :)

Comment: This is all the same UV map. When you select a portion of a mesh in edit mode, UVs are only displayed for the selected geometry, so you are only viewing different parts of the same UV map here by selecting only geometry with some specific materials assigned to it. This has nothing to do with accessing different UV maps.